# $dom->loadHTMLFile() hangs up in WordPress theme

Tags: php, wordpress

When I create a simple `test.php` file with the code

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://localhost');
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
print_r($dom);
?>
```

put it in the root of WordPress website and follow by the link `localhost/test.php`, I successfully and immediately receive the output like

> DOMDocument Object ( [doctype] => (object value omitted) [implementation] => (object value omitted) [documentElement] => (object value omitted) [actualEncoding] => utf-8 ...

But if I add the code to WordPress theme file for example to the end of the `footer.php` and load any page of website, the client hangs up (page keeps loading) and I see in the Processes tab of the Windows Task Manager that the `httpd.exe` (Apache) process keeps consuming more and more operative memory until I stopped the page loading.

What's the reason and how to make `$dom->loadHTMLFile()` be working under the WordPress theme?

ps. I noticed that the first line

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
```

doesn't cause any problem but that does the line

```
$dom->loadHTMLFile('...');
```

Comment: When you use `$dom->loadHTMLFile()` to load a page of a website that uses `$dom->loadHTMLFile()` to load a page of a website that uses `$dom->loadHTMLFile()` to load a page of a website that uses `$dom->loadHTMLFile()` to load a page of a website that uses `$dom->loadHTMLFile()` to load a page of a website.... You get the idea? This is called "endless recursion".

Comment: Yes, I got it ;) Thanks

Comment: So what simple condition can I add to stop the endless recursion?

Comment: Well, that's another can of worms. You can't know that you're in a recursion, unless you tell yourself so. Perhaps an extra parameter on the URL? Something like: `https://example.com/page.html?id=12&do_not_recurse=true`, and then check for that `do_not_recurse` parameter before you do `$dom->loadHTMLFile()`. The extra parameter is only needed when you use `$dom->loadHTMLFile()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could prevent recursion:

```
if (!isset($_GET["do_not_recurse"])) {
    $url = "https://example.com/page.html?id=12";
    $arg = (strpos($url, "?") === FALSE ? '?' : '&') . "do_not_recurse=true";   
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTMLFile($url . $arg);
}
```

Comment: You probably meant `$_GET`, not `$_POST` ?

Comment: And you missed the leading `$url` in the `loadHTMLFile()`, you only specified the trailing parameter, it should be `$url . (strpos($url, "?") === FALSE ...`

Comment: @stckvrw Yeah, sorry. Well spotted. Were is my head?! I'm doing to many things at the same time. I will correct the answer.